# Unable to load the manifest for package

Tags: ros, rospy, rosbridge, rosbridge-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rosbridge with catkin packages.

`ros_rope` (the webserver for the GUI) is started with a python script. At the same time rosbridge_websocket is started. Here's my launchfile:

```
<launch>
        <node name="ros_rope_server" pkg="ros_rope" type="server.py" output="screen" />
        <node name="ros_rope_bridge" pkg="rosbridge_server" type="rosbridge_websocket" />
        <node name="ros_rope_helper" pkg="ros_rope_helper" type="listener.py" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

Additionally there's another ROS node `ros_rope_test` providing the different services for the gui:

```
<launch>
        <node name="ros_rope_test_server" pkg="ros_rope_test" type="rope_server.py" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

I start both packages with `roslaunch ros_rope server` and `roslaunch ros_rope_test server`.

When the `ros_rope` executes the first service call to `ros_rope_test`, it throws the following exception:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1396864502.429285] [Client 0] [id: call_service:/get_process_list:2] call_service InvalidPackageException: Unable to load the manifest for package ros_rope_test. Caused by: ros_rope_test
```

The next calls work without any problem. So this exception is only thrown once after the node is started.

How can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149531/unable-to-load-the-manifest-for-package/) by [Pro](https://answers.ros.org/users/14476/pro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-04-12**:
Did you make sure service is available before you call service?

**Comment by [Pro](https://answers.ros.org/users/14476/pro/) on 2014-04-13**:
Yes, I can call the service with `rosservice call` -> The service is definetly up and running. I can also reproduce this behavior by simply restarting the `rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket`. Thus rosbridge causes the error after each restart. Maybe it's related to catkin packages?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-04-13**:
Can you provide any test code? So I can dig out the problem. I am not sure how to reproduce the given issue.

**Comment by [Pro](https://answers.ros.org/users/14476/pro/) on 2014-04-14**:
Here are two ros packages to reproduce this behavior: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5acl60sygzjyf51/gui_process_editor.tar.gz
Just `catkin_make` and start them with `roslaunch rosbridge_test_service server` and `roslauch rosbridge_test_webapp server`. Then open your browser http://localhost:3000

**Comment by [Pro](https://answers.ros.org/users/14476/pro/) on 2014-04-14**:
It looks like this problem only occurs when using backbone.js (see the comments in main.js file within the webapp folder)

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-04-14**:
It complains about ros_rope package missing when I tried to start rosbridge_test_webapp server. Can you share this? Or any simple way to replicate the problem would be good too.

**Comment by [Pro](https://answers.ros.org/users/14476/pro/) on 2014-04-14**:
Oh, sorry, here again: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h088mhtyqwf34zw/rosbridge_test_2.tar.gz  Unfortunately I didn't found any simpler way than creating these two packages...

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-04-16**:
I am following this. Please wait me for test. I just got too many things are loaded on my todo list these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some experiment, I firstly confirms that ServiceRequests  works fine with the code below.

```
  var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros();

  // If there is an error on the backend, an 'error' emit will be emitted.
  ros.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  // Find out exactly when we made a connection.
  ros.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Connection made!');
    var getListService = new ROSLIB.Service({
      ros : ros,
      name : '/get_list',
      serviceType : 'rosbridge_test_service/GetList'
    });
    var request = new ROSLIB.ServiceRequest({});
    getListService.callService(request, function(result) {
       console.log(result);
     });
  });

  // Create a connection to the rosbridge WebSocket server.
  ros.connect('ws://localhost:9090'); //98
```

I figured out that your code call the service twice almost simultaneously. And it seems to cause a problem when rosbridge creates a message cache. I have tried to investigate to solve this issue but the exception arises from ros core library which I can't track down more deeply.

Thus, I would suggest to clean up the server code logic to call service once. rosbridge is able to handle multiple connections and multiple service calls. However, this case was too extreme...

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0